# How to find documentation of dbruntime.dbutils.FileInfo class

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm relatively new to Python, Spark and Cloud. I'm currently using the method `dbutils.fs.ls(path)`, the databricks documentation doesn't specify that it returns a FileInfo object. When I do a "type()" of the elements of the result of executing the "ls", the type is `dbruntime.dbutils.FileInfo`. I cannot backtrack any documentation of this Class, I only know about it's methods using the `dir(dbutils.fs.ls(path)[0])` command.

How do I properly move around this kind of problems where there is not a direct documentation? I expected it to be some kind of Python specific class but it is not as it is using dbruntime.

I tried searching the official databricks documentation, stackoverflow questions, Microsoft and AWS documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To access files on a Databricks File System (DBFS) mount using local file APIs, you will need to prepend `"/dbfs"` to the file path.

```
with open('/dbfs/mnt/test_file.json', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line)
```

Documentation at [Databricks File System](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dbfs/index.html#local-file-apis) for more details, especially regarding any limitations.

I have refered question related your ask where working on a Spark Cluster using a Databricks Notebook a command to list files and see that file exists in the specified location.

you can **Reference:** [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52731118/databricks-dbutils-fs-ls-shows-files-however-reading-them-throws-an-io-error) thread.

Also you can try the `dbutils.fs.head("file path")`

To list available commands for a utility along with a short description of each command, run `.help()` after the programmatic name for the utility.

This example lists available commands for the Databricks File System (DBFS) utility.

```
dbutils.fs.help()
```

[List available commands for a utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-utils#--list-available-commands-for-a-utility)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to follow the few steps that are regarding to the DBFS

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).